# What would be the best way to control Transaction Per Min (TPM) in given time duration to replicate actual user load with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Hope you are doing well.
I got a requirement to design load test as per given TPM for given duration

```
• Add 3000 TPM in 0Min-10min
• Add 3000 TPM in 10Min-20Min
• Add 3000 TPM in 20Min-30Min
• Add 20000 TPM in 30Min-45Min
• Add 3000 TPM in 45Min-50Min
• Add 10000 TPM in 50Min-60Min
• Add 3000 TPM in 50Min-60Min
• Add 3000 TPM in 60Min-70Min
• Then maintain consistent load 70Min- 120Min
```

I have tried with with normal Thread Group and with Ultimate thread group. Also tried using *Constant throughput timer*. But not able to replicate customer's behavior.
Is there some way to replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be going for the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/)

It has [`load_profile` custom property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) so if you add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

```
load_profile=const(50,10m) const(100,10m) const(150,10m) const(483,15m) const(533,5m) const(700,10m) const(750,10m) const(800,60m)
```

You will have the following test setup:

[image]

Not sure whether it replicates "customer's behaviour", but it replicates the workload from your question.